# Move text below application icon in GridView

Tags: android, list, icons

Hello Guys How can arrange appname under the icon ? If you need i give the source.

[image]

You can see the code used to create this view here:

```
package com.example.draw;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AppInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> mListAppInfo;
    private PackageManager mPackManager;

    public AppInfoAdapter(Context c, List<ApplicationInfo> list, PackageManager pm) {
        mContext = c;
        mListAppInfo = list;
        mPackManager = pm;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListAppInfo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mListAppInfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get the selected entry
        ApplicationInfo entry = mListAppInfo.get(position);

        // reference to convertView
        View v = convertView;

        // inflate new layout if null
        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_appinfo, null);
        }

        // load controls from layout resources
        ImageView ivAppIcon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);



        // set data to display
        ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));



        // return view
        return v;
    }
}
```

Text come from 
    **TextView tvAppName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
   tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));**

main_appinfo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
      android:scaleType="center" 
      android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code. Probably, `getView()` of the adapter.

Comment: +1 for the best use of an apostrophe I have ever seen!

Comment: @User117 here you have the code http://pastebin.com/mN0hs5z6

Comment: @Fogmeister i'm sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: This shouldn't be receiving down votes. It's a genuine question.

Comment: Please list R.layout.activity_appinfo.xml file

Comment: Are you sure that the above screenshot is based on AppInfoAdapter ? because I don't see where you set the text !

Comment: @Mr.Me EDITED look now.

Comment: Please put the code for textView where it belong , your code still seems missing something. it should be a linearLayout xml file with imageView and textView as childs, or at least a textview with compound drawable !

Answer (score 0):

The `LinearLayout` in layout file horizontal, make it vertical.

`android:orientation="horizontal"` to `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score -1):

App Icon and title format is part of the **Home Screen App** in android, you can't modify its look.

If you want you can create your own Home Screen App and do whatever you want with it.

Here is an example for home screen apps : [Home App Android sdk Sample](http://gitorious.org/replicant/development/trees/d2f2b1d7b77d06bce8cf9340171cf6c25cd720c4/samples/Home)

Comment: This doesn't look to be a screenshot of the Home Screen App as he's provided his code for the adapter.

Comment: There are many home screen apps out there , I'm not sure how is he using his code or why, but the above sample contains a gridview that has apps with their icon in the way he wants... hence the answer